# How to set up WIFI connection upon installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, settings

I just installed **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** and was asked to create a Ubuntu One Account. However, it said no connection is found after I put in everything, and I don't see the option to connect to my WIFI anywhere. The ***Network*** Section in **Settings** only include Wired and VPN.

I just changed the hard disk so this machine is rather clean, I think. How can I set up my WIFI connection?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

Try open menu and search for Driver, or Driver Manager. It's a software installed as default at Ubuntu, but you can install it if not exist. It's possible you will find - open the software - a message asking you about a driver (probably the right). You will need to choose the driver and check it as trustworthy.

If the driver is ok and wireless is not able, you will need to press the key responsible to enable/disable wireless (if it's a notebook).

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you! Although the only search result is "Additional Drivers" and it's blank. Now I'm thinking I may have bigger problem concerning hard drive because I just googled "install driver manager" and everybody said there should be something listed up there instead of "No proprietary drivers are in use".